# BQ - Remove array from other array

Tags: google-bigquery

I have a simple query like this.

```
select 
       array_agg (....) as A,
       array_agg (....) as B
from
       ....
```

The result contains

```
A: [1, 2, 3, 4],
B: [1, 2, 3, 5]
```

I need to have the "B" which are not present in A.

```
A: [1, 2, 3, 4],
B: [5]
```

Is there any function which I could make use of.?

Answer (score 0):

Use below approach

```
select *, array(
  select _b
  from unnest(B) as _b
  where not _b in unnest(A)
) as B_minus_A
from current_result
```

[image]